I want to display images loaded in the image folder
https://github.com/asyml/vision-transformer-pytorch
I want to display the image loaded with "ImageNetDataLoader" using the code in the link above.
I get an error　TypeError: 'iterator' object is not subscriptable
class ImageNetDataLoader(DataLoader):
def init(self, data_dir, split='train', image_size=224, batch_size=16, num_workers=8):
    if split == 'train':
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((image_size, image_size)),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
        ])
    else:
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((image_size, image_size)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
        ])

    self.dataset = ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(data_dir, split), transform=transform)
    
    super(ImageNetDataLoader, self).__init__(
        dataset=self.dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True if split == 'train' else False,
        num_workers=num_workers)
        
    imgs = iter(self.dataset)
    print("image shape ==>;",imgs[0].shape)
    pic = transforms.ToPILImage(mode='RGB')(imgs[0])
    plt.imshow(pic)
    print("Label is ",labels[0].numpy())
    

